# How to call function from other local file Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I tried like this from `main.js`

```
// Modules to control application life and create native browser window
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const parser = require('./parser.js');
parser.parseHash(url)
```

But got error that: `parser.parseHash` is not function

```
// parser.js file
function parseHash(url) {
    ...
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// parser.js
exports.parseHash = function (url) {
    ...
};

//main.js
const parseHash = require('./parser').parseHash;
parseHash(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you exporting parseHash function in parser.js file?

```
module.exports  = {
parseHash,
}
```

Comment: From `parser` file to `main`

Answer (score -1):

You need to export the function like this:

```
// parser.js file
function parseHash(url) {
    ...
}

module.exports = {
    parseHash: parseHash
}
```